# Specifying symbols/source path in XCode 4 for Debugging

Tags: xcode, macos, debugging, xcode4, xcode4.5

I've a .app package that I want to debug which does not contain symbols. However, I've a separate folder which contains all the symbols of binaries in the app. And in another folder, I have all the app source code. The path in symbols is different from the source path on my system. I tried google for a long time but surprisingly did not find any solution. How can I debug app:

1. Using symbols which are in a separate folder.
2. And, using sources which are in location different from the location in symbol files.

Help greatly appreciated.